# dovecot namespace: empty prefix vs. list=yes

Tags: dovecot, imap, namespaces

I just upgraded dovecot from 2.1.7 to 2.2.13, and my previously working configuration broke.

I have one user with an empty `prefix` in his default namespace:

```
Error: XXXX: Initialization failed: namespace configuration error: list=yes requires prefix=yes to end with separator
Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

The prefix is set to empty via the userdb:

```
XXXX:YYYY::::::userdb_namespace/inbox/prefix=
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any other configuration. With

```
XXXX:YYYY::::::userdb_namespace/inbox/prefix=.
```

I get

```
namespace configuration error: list=yes requires prefix=. not to start with separator
```

What is the correct way to get the old behaviour with 2.2.13?

Comment: It might be that this problem is independent of namespaces, and rather the more general question: “How to set a configuration variable to the empty string via `userdb`?”

Comment: It sounds like your prefix definition is wrong. You can't have `prefix=.` if `separator=.`. You would probably need something like `prefix=INBOX.` or maybe an empty prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the issue by defining the namespace in the configuration twice (`inbox` and `inbox_alt`, with the latter with `disabled = yes`), and put this in the userdb:

```
  userdb_namespace/inbox/disabled=yes userdb_namespace/inbox_alt/disabled=no
```

This way, I could successfully set `prefix` in `inbox_alt` to the empty string.